# Inable to download file from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-blob-storage

I have an SSIS package how connects to Azure and recovers a json file as configuration file.
It worked perfectly until the day when, without explanation, I started to have an error.

Note that the connection was successful and that my IP address is whitelisted.

Code

```
115  StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
116  CloudStorageAccount storage = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
117  CloudBlobClient client = storage.CreateCloudBlobClient();
118  CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference(configFileContainer);
119  CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(configFileName);
120
121  string configJson = blob.DownloadText();  // ERROR
```

Error

```
Client and server cannot communicate because they do not have any algorithms in common.
```

Stack trace

```
    Error: 0x1 at ST - Load Config: An error occurred while sending the request.   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<ExecuteAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where the exception was raised ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<ExecuteSync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.RunWithoutSynchronizationContext[T](Func`1 actionToRun)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadRangeToStream(Stream target, Nullable`1 offset, Nullable`1 length, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadToStream(Stream target, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.DownloadText(Encoding encoding, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
   at ST_9b0ac6493260451aa379f7276b92d98e.ScriptMain.Main() dans ...344f55fca5c54a4f832c7376bc4a2b16\ScriptMain.cs:ligne 121
Error: 0x6 at ST - Load Config: The script returned an error result.
Task failed: ST - Load Config
```

Comment: can you please check with this document:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b21df46-357f-46be-8107-9c014879a995/microsoftwindowsazurestoragestorageexception-while-uploading-byte-stream-to-azure-blob?forum=windowsazuredata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the connection protocol used is outdated. Azure expects TLS1.2 protocol.

Two ways to solve the problem:

- On your machine => With enabling TLS protocol and desabling the olders versions.
- In the code => Disable obsolete protocols and force the use of TLS1.2 with adding this code befor the connexion to Azure.

Like that :

```
108  // Remove insecure protocols (SSL3, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1)
109  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol &= ~SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
110  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol &= ~SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
111  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol &= ~SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
112  // Add TLS 1.2
113  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
114
115  StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
116  CloudStorageAccount storage = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
117  CloudBlobClient client = storage.CreateCloudBlobClient();
118  CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference(configFileContainer);
119  CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(configFileName);
```